# warning: the compiler can assume that the address of ‘x’ will never be NULL

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I written the following code and got two warnings. Searching online is still very confusing.

```cpp
template <typename T>
LogMgr &operator << (const T &t)
{
    m_Stream << t;
    return *this;
}
```

warning: the compiler can assume that the address of ‘t’ will never be NULL [-Waddress]

warning: nonnull argument ‘t’ compared to NULL [-Wnonnull-compare]

Comment: It has to do with the compiler making certain assumptions, and those assumptions could lead to erroneous code. See http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/nonnull_gcc_attribute.html

Comment: Please show enough code to reproduce the warning.

Comment: I find it very unlikely that the error message points to that particular piece of code. From the message, it looks like you’re doing `if (&t != NULL)...` somewhere.

Comment: What is `m_Stream`?  What does `m_Stream << t` do?  Will it try to print the address of `t`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm m_Stream is a stringstream.Yes, I am using overloaded << to output some logs.

Comment: @Steve Can I ignore this warning directly?

Comment: If you add some code that shows how your `operator<<` you currently have in your question is being called, and the overloaded `operator<<` used by `m_Stream << t` we might be able to determine an answer to your implied question.  What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass argument by reference ( t ) then it can't be NULL. (Pass by pointer, it can be NULL)